Nginx ssl_verify_client on does not deny requests sent with no client cert
With ssl_verify_client on in my nginx, I would expect that requests that have no client cert are denied.  But they are allowed.
eg use a web browser to GET /foo/bar, response is 200 OK. I would expect it to be 401 or 403 instead. Because of course the web browser does not send the client cert with the request.
Have I configured this incorrectly? Or is there another step also required to deny these requests?
My server is api.example.com and I have a wildcard cert *.example.com.  The client has provided their cert and CA cert.
server {
  listen 443 default_server ssl;
  server_name _;

  # bundle = my cert + CA cert
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.com.bundle.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.com.key;

  # bundle = other side's client cert + CA cert
  # ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/client/client-bundle.pem;
  
  ssl_verify_client on;
  ssl_verify_depth 2;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
}


Your nginx is working as expected. The client certificate verification merely verifies the client certificates, and stores the result in $ssl_client_verify variable, but doesn't deny anything by itself. It's you who should describe how nginx should allow/deny the access based on this variable value in your config, probably using if () {} clause.

Wow thats crazy.  You are correct, it does nothing at all except for set a variable.  This is not mentioned or even hinted at in the docs.  I added if ($ssl_client_verify != "SUCCESS") and its good now.
